# How to store large user-specific data

Tags: mongodb, database

So I'm in the middle of planning a little web app that will require quite large amounts of data stored on a user level, in one case, the system would take a large object from a system level and make a "user specific" version, a user can have multiple ones of these. Simplest would be to compare it to a form stored in a google spreadsheet, where the user is expected to use the template spreadsheet, then change not only the answers but also the question. 
Security wise I am quite OK

In the second case there is requirement to store multiple objects, size about 250k to maybe 3mb, once again on a user specific level, with a potential to move it to a system level so additional users can access it. As an example, say the user can upload pictures, but may not want to share all of them. However, a user may choose to "publish" a small number of them because they are happy with those specific pictures.

What design patterns should I consider using specifically around web apps where the user have decent amounts of data? For example, would it make most sense to use a single large database and have a table that keeps track of resources or create separate tables per user?

I have considered putting it all in a mongo database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach may be wrong.

If you want to store user based binary data and make it accessible for the user itself or the community, you would need a hierarchic structure like so:

- userid1

  - pic1,pic2,pic3
- userid2

  - pic4,pic5,pic6
- community

  - pic7,pic8

You could then grant read permissions to "community" for all users, and permission for each user to its own directory.

Usually there is nothing wrong using a database to store binary files if you consider partitioning, role permissions and an applicable interface to access the data.

My suggestion is to use a binary repository like Artifactory.
It provides hierarchic structures, simple search queries using HTTP requests and has caching abilities for frequently queried objects.
I also think that http requests are a lot easier to use and also there is an abstraction layer to the data which is more secure.

Artifactory is free.

Comment: Thank you very much. When you say userid1: pic1, pic2, pic3 would I be right in saying that that would be a reference to the pic rather than the pic itself?

Comment: In artifactory you store binaries. The reference to pictures will be the URL.
E.g. if user1 posts a picture, you would do a HTTP post request with the picture binary data to artifactory.
This will make it available to the user by a simple HTTP GET request. Imagine it like so:
http://localhost:8081/artifactory/images/userid1/pic1 will be your reference. You just need the UserID and PicID. To see all pictures of the user you would simply call the URL without picture ID and it will return a directory structure with all available pictures.